ERROR 409 "CONFLICT" when making a post request to sanity api to create a mutation
`I'm currently working with Sanity in my project in NextJs 14. it's a page that allows ppl to rent apartments. After the payment is complete (Argentinian Payment method "Mercado Pago" Used). The payment configuration accepts a url to send the notification about the payment information. I pass the url of my route to the webhook "api/webhook" and I can check the payment. Everything great up until there. When I verify that the payment is indeed approved. I call a function called createBooking and I pass an object with the data of the booking that is stored in the payment as metadata, the function receives it correctly I checked logging it. And when I do the post request to create the mutation it doesn't work. On closer inspection I get an 409 error from there, and I checked the object and all the configurations, tokens, dataset, url, etc and it's all good.
This is in the route where I pass the object to the function:
This first line is where I get a 200 status ifthe payment is approved and I extract the metadata object with the required info.
I have tried passing "metadata" alon (outside of the object), alone with spread operated, and even between curly braces, none worked. Although with curly braces it created the mutation, but empty with no data in the correspondingfields. I also checked that the schemas matched by creating one through sanity studio and seeing the JSON from the object.
worth to note also I did try to change the api version or creating a new token to see what'd change
`
   if (response.status === 200){
    const data = response.data;
           const { status } = data;
           const {
               metadata: {
                   adults,
                   checkin_date: checkInDate,
                   checkout_date: checkOutDate,
                   discount,
                   apartment,
                   user,
                   price: totalPrice,
                   children,
                   number_of_days: numberOfDays,
               }
           } = data
           if (status === "approved") {
               const res = await createBooking({
                   adults: Number(adults),
                   checkInDate: String(checkInDate),
                   checkOutDate: String(checkOutDate),
                   discount: Number(discount),
                   apartment: String(apartment),
                   user: String(user),
                   totalPrice: Number(totalPrice),
                   children: Number(children),
                   numberOfDays: Number(numberOfDays)
               });
               if (res) return new NextResponse("Creada", { status: 201 })

This is the function
  export const createBooking = async ({
  adults,
  apartment,
  checkInDate,
  checkOutDate,
  children,
  discount,
  totalPrice,
  user,
  numberOfDays
  }: CreateBookingDto) => {
  const mutation = {
      mutations: [{
          create: {
              _type: "booking",
              user: { _type: 'reference', _ref: user },
              apartment: { _type: 'reference', _ref: apartment },
              checkInDate,
              checkOutDate,
              adults,
              children,
              numberOfDays,
              totalPrice,
              discount,
          },
      },
      ],
  };
  try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
  "https://${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID}.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/mutate/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET}",
          mutation, {
          headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer ${process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_TOKEN",
          }
      })

      return data
  }
  catch (err) {
      console.log("\nERROR", err)
  }
  }

I at least expected the mutation to create with some of the data or something. Also,     almost forgot, but I did try to use the props in the function via dot notation since I     received an object. Worth a shot. didn't work and I can't find much about it. Specially with an Argentinian payment method. I am open to try anything, any help would be much appretiated 
